# Populate jQuery UI autocomplete with data from database using JSP+AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of days now and I'm not getting anything with the code I have. I have a form that has a textbox that needs to list outside salesmen that I am trying to use autocomplete.

This is the code for the form (doorform2.jsp)

```html
<script>
    $("#outsideSales").autocomplete({source: "outsideIn.jsp",minLength: 2});
</script>

<input type="text" name="outsideSalesman" id="outsideSales" required>
```

This is the code that I am using to get data from my database to use for the autocomplete

```
<%
Connection con = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://nemesis:1433;instanceName=gfi;databaseName=NationalFormsRepository;user=portal;password=P0rtal");
stmt = con.createStatement();

String outside = request.getParameter("outsideSalesman");

ArrayList<String> outsideSalesmenNames = new ArrayList<String>();
String outsideSalesman = "SELECT outsideSalesName FROM tbl_outsideSales WHERE outsideSalesName like '%"+outside+"%'";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(outsideSalesman);

while(rs.next())
{
    outsideSalesmenNames.add(rs.getString("outsideSalesName"));
}
out.println(outsideSalesmenNames);

%>
```

I've tried to follow several tutorials online but most of the ones that I have been following are for php not jsp or they are for older versions of jquery autocomplete. I feel like I am missing something small but have been looking at it to long to see it. Can anyone take a look and see if I am missing anything?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, your code is not wrapped inside [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). The following will not work as expected:

```
<script>
$("#outsideSales").dosomething();
</script>
<!-- Note: #outsideSales does not exist before this line -->
<input id="outsideSales">
```

Revise your code like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#outsideSales").dosomething();
});
</script>
<input id="outsideSales">
```

#2: when you specify a URL as the source parameter, jQuery UI will send a request that contains the query string parameter `term`. So you need to modify your code accordingly:

```
String outside = request.getParameter("term");
```

#3: the jQuery UI expects a *valid* JSON instead of a string. So instead of this:

```
[Jack, Jill, John]
```

Your program needs to output:

```
["Jack", "Jill", "John"]
```

PS: your query is open to SQL injection.

Comment: Ok, I changed the request.getParameter to "term" and I added `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(outsideSalesmenNames));` but I still don't get suggestions when I type in the textbox. I have an import of '<%@page import= "//raw.github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/master/JSONArray.java" %>`

Comment: Open the AJAX page (i.e. `http://website.com/outsideIn.jsp?term=test`) in browser and make sure it is working.

Comment: I am getting an error with the JSON part of the code. The whole error message exceeds the size of the message box here but this is the start of the message. HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP.  The page works if I remove the JSON code. I think it may be the java file that I am linking to.

Comment: It seems to be in the JSON library file that I am using. I downloaded the gson library and will try that.

Comment: Ok, I added the Gson library to my preject but I am now getting Gson class not found when I run the AJAX page. This is the include that I am using `<%@page import= "com.google.gson.Gson" %>` and this is the code to convert the array. `Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(outsideSalesmenNames);
 out.println(json);`

Comment: This is the error if you need it. org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
package com.google.gson does not exist

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /outsideIn.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Gson
  location: class org.apache.jsp.outsideIn_jsp

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 14 in the jsp file: /outsideIn.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Gson
  location: class org.apache.jsp.outsideIn_jsp

Comment: Ok,I got the gson class to work and I get the right info back when I print out the json array `["Chad Trombley","Josh Rowen","Robert Harris","Robert Klemick","Robert Morris","Rocky Carlino","Taurean Rondeau"]`, but I still am not getting the autocomplete list on the calling page.

Comment: Not wrapping your jQuery code inside [`$(document).ready(function(){ /* code goes here */ })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is a bad idea. Do this and see if it helps.

Comment: Ok, I revised the code to this on the form page but I still don't get any autocomplete suggestions. `<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#outsideSales").autocomplete({
       source: "outsideIn.jsp",
       minLength: 2
       });
      });
      </script>`

Comment: The autocomplete on the form page works if I copy the output from outsideIn.jsp into the source location of the form page, so I must be missing. Would it be possible to send you the 2 files to take a quick look?

Comment: Can you put the two pages (html form and outsideIn.jsp) somewhere online so that I can view? The jsp page should be working, even if it throws errors.

Comment: Here are links to the 2 files in my dropbox. [doorform2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73117310/doorform2.jsp) [outsideIn](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73117310/outsideIn.jsp)

Comment: I did not get a chance to run the scripts, but I notice that you are sending `doctype`, `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>` etc in outsideIn.jsp. No, this is not how you send JSON; JSON must be on its own, not wrapped inside HTML.

Comment: I removed all of the html tags and it is working now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your **outsideIn.jsp** must be return a **JSON** formated data.

From official docs: *"The datasource is a server-side script which returns JSON data, specified via a simple URL for the source-option. In addition, the minLength-option is set to 2 to avoid queries that would return too many results and the select-event is used to display some feedback."*

See here for more informations: [link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Cheers :)